# Python Logging Handler Filter Unable to Filter

Tags: python, logging, filter

Log file contain many rows with the string "[websockets.client.read_frame:1152]" from websockets.client. I want to filter them out and tried the following code:

```
class LoggingFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        def __init__(self):
            logging.Filter.__init__(self)
        
        needle = "[websockets.client.read_frame:1152]"
        if needle in record.msg:
            logger.debug(f"Needle {needle} found in haystack: {record}")
            return 0
        return 1

daily_rotating_filehandler = DailyRotatingFileHandler(sys.path[0] + '\logs', width=4, maxBytes=100000, backupCount=999, encoding='utf-8')
daily_rotating_filehandler.addFilter(LoggingFilter())

logging.basicConfig(
        #handlers=[RotatingFileHandler('./logs/{:%Y%m%d-%H%M}.log'.format(datetime.now()), maxBytes=100000, backupCount=100, encoding='utf-8')],
        #handlers=[DailyRotatingFileHandler(sys.path[0] + '\logs', width=4, maxBytes=100000, backupCount=999, encoding='utf-8')],
        handlers=[daily_rotating_filehandler],
        level=my_global.log_level,
        format="[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s [%(name)s.%(funcName)s:%(lineno)d] %(message)s",
        datefmt='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')

# Creating an object
logger = logging.getLogger()
#logger.addHandler(daily_rotating_filehandler)

# Change logging levels for other packages
logging.getLogger('websockets.protocol').setLevel(logging.WARNING)
logging.getLogger('websockets.client').addFilter(LoggingFilter())
logging.getLogger('websockets').addFilter(LoggingFilter())
```

Unfortunately, said log entries still make it through. What am I missing?

Update:

Thanks to @Mark's answer below, the modification needed to make the code work was:

```
class LoggingFilter(logging.Filter):

    def __init__(self):
        logging.Filter.__init__(self)
            
    def filter(self, record):
        if record.name == "websockets.client" and record.funcName == "read_frame":
            return 0
        return 1
```

Comment: Can you try running your code in a debugger to see what your filter is getting?  btw, your constructor definition is in the wrong place.  It should be above the `filter` method, not inside it.  I don't expect that it's doing any harm there though...it's just not being used.

Comment: @CryptoFool, good suggestion. I'll do that next time. For now, a solution was found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your filter is that you expect the value in the log to match the record msg.  That is, you are searching the record.msg for "[websockets.client.read_frame:1152]".  However, that string is generated by other fields in the logging record.  You can figure it out from your format:

```
"[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s [%(name)s.%(funcName)s:%(lineno)d] %(message)s"
```

So, the string ""[websockets.client.read_frame:1152]" is really generated by this portion of the format string:

```
[%(name)s.%(funcName)s:%(lineno)d]
```

However, you could change the code to eliminate the logging of line 1152 on the funcName of "read_frame" like this (I hope):

```
    if record.lineno == 1152 and record.funcName == "read_fname":
        logger.debug(f"Needle {needle} found in haystack: {record}")
        return False
    return True
```

I haven't tested the code above (for instance, I assume that record.lineno is an int, so you'll need to work a bit with that.

Also, I'll point that the field you are using is msg, which is really the string passed into the logging call.  For instance,

```
logger.info("Here's a message")
```

In the example above, `msg == "Here's a message"`.  msg does not contain all of the other values (like the logger name or the level or the lineno).

Comment: Thank you! Your detailed answer was the solution I needed. The original post was updated with the code I ended up using.